# How to refresh the Label text in my app when i click the Refresh Button?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I Want this app to refresh the 'label' data (Which is a datetime) when i click the Refresh Button.

I tried pushButton.clicked.connect(ui.setupUi(MainWindow)), but it is not working, im out of clue how to do that.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import datetime


class Ui_MainWindow(object):    

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(200, 200)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 30, 121, 61))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):

        import datetime
        dt = str(datetime.datetime.now())
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", dt))


        pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 150, 75, 23))
        pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")


        # pushButton.clicked.connect(ui.setupUi(MainWindow))

        pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Refresh"))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)    
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

After clicking the Refresh button the time should update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really shouldn't re-initialize the ui for that, but just set the text for the label.
Also, since `datetime.datetime.now()` is "dynamic", you should use a lambda or, better, a dedicated slot.

The "simpler" solution, based on your code, is use this where you have the commented code:

```
    pushButton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.label.setText(str(datetime.datetime.now())))
```

Or, sometimes better, the same thing in a specific method:

```
    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        # ...
        pushButton.clicked.connect(self.setCurrentDate)
        # ...

    def setCurrentDate(self):
        self.label.setText(str(datetime.datetime.now()))
```

Comment: The first solution worked as expected. (which solves my problem)

but i will try the second solution, as it is better, and will be effective when i have to refresh lots of data on a single click.

Answer (score 0):

You were there almost. Using `pushButton.clicked.connect()` is correct, but you don't need to recall the initUI function.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import datetime


class Ui_MainWindow(object):

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(200, 200)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 30, 121, 61))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):

        dt = str(datetime.datetime.now())
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", dt))

        pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 150, 75, 23))
        pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")

        pushButton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.update_time())

        pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Refresh"))

    def update_time(self):

        self.label.setText(str(datetime.datetime.now()))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I made it in a seperate function so you can add more things to it if you want. You could also make `pushButton` a class member so you can check the state in `update_time()`. Or you could pass it as an function argument.